# How to transform a csv to combine matching rows?

Tags: bash, script, csv

I have a CSV file with some transaction data. Let's say date, volume, price and direction (sell/buy). Additionally there is a ID for each transaction and on each closing transaction (the newer one) there is a reference to the corresponding transaction. Classical database referencing.

Now I want to do some statistics and draw some plots. This could be done via Octave, LaTeX/TikZ, Gnuplot or whatever. To do this I need both buy and sell price in one row. My thought was to preprocess the CSV to get another CSV containing the needed information and then to do the statistics.
In the end I'd like to have a solution based on scripts and not on a spreadsheet as data might change often (exported from online DB).

My actual solution (see http://paste.ubuntu.com/6262822/ ) is a bash script that parses the CSV line by line and checks if there exists a corresponding transaction. If found, a new row is written to the destination CSV. If not a warning is printed.

The bad news: For each row in the source file I have to read the whole file a few times. This causes long running times of 10sec for 300 lines. As the line number might rise soon (>10k lines), this is not perfect.
I am aware, that there are many shells to be opened in the script which might cause the performance problems.

Now my questions:

- Is bash/awk/sed/.... a good way to do things?
- Should I first import all data into a "real" local database to use SQL?
- Is there an easy way to achieve the desired results?

Comment: Sounds like a perfect case for MS Access to me (or MySQL)

Comment: MS is not possible as I am using a pure linux box. Though MySQL (or similar) is quite an option. Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact, I solved the problem by using PostgreSQL (was already available on the laptop). I added the data via `\copy` to a temporary table and did some views, selects etc. In the end everything (loading data, creating multiple output files and pivot tables) takes less than half a second. Perfect.

Thanks.